# How to get the value of html element with id suffix using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

How to get the value of the HTML input type with dynamic id name using jQuery

```
    <td><input id="j_id_id23:hiddenId" type="hidden" name="j_id_id23:hiddenId" value="3" /></td>
```

The input id name is generated dynamically.  So the key for finding specific element is by **hiddenId** which I can attached to the html input component.

I have done this so far but returning undefined

```
$('input[id^="hiddenId"]')
```

Comment: Begins-with, just like regex: `$('input[id^="hiddenId"]')`. Ends-with: `$('input[id$="hiddenId"]')`

Answer (score 0):

If id value ends up with known substring `hiddenId` you can use selector:

```
$('input[id$="hiddenId"]')
```

Comment: This is not worth an answer - but at least yours is correct

Comment: Unfortunately I have no enough reputation for commenting)

Comment: That’s ok. Already plenty of comments under the question